# each loop not working

Tags: jquery, loops, each

trying to loop through some testimonials and it doesn't loop through, just goes to the end of the comments and stops. have tried placing the each() in various locations and it still doesn't loop. Been trying to figure this out most of last night and can't seem to make it work.

my current code is:

```
$('.home-customer-comments').children('.customer-comment').each(function() {
    // Set first div to show
    $('.customer-comment:first').show();

    // Begin the loop, fade out, find next div, fade that div in, end the process and append back to main div.
$('.customer-comment').each(setInterval(function() {
    $('.customer-comment:first').fadeOut().hide().next('.customer-comment').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.customer-comment');
}, 1000))



});
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML please?

Comment: Passing the result of `setInterval()` (a number) to `.each()` (expects a function) doesn't make sense.

Comment: Maybe you also want to use $('.home-customer-comments').find instead of $('.home-customer-comments').children? Or are the "customer-comment" a direct child of "home-customer-comments"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('.customer-comment:first').show();
    setInterval(function () {
        $('.customer-comment:first').fadeOut().hide().next('.customer-comment').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.home-customer-comments');
    }, 1000);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MPsWC/)

Comment: Thanks this worked! will mark it as answer when it lets me :-)